# SourceTree github repo not valid url

Tags: url, github, repository

When I install SourceTree on my OSX, setup a Github account via ssh, and then copy/paste Github url/clone, It always says "Not a valid sourcepath/URL" even though the url is valid.

I have searched the web for the same issues, and found some interesting solutions, but non of them worked in my case. I have tried removing all of SourceTree's settings and completely uninstall the APP, but same stuff is happening. Also tried removing my account, removing ssh key etc. (I have git installed).

All of my connected repositories is shown under the tab remote, but I just can't clone anything.

The Github repo url is: https://github.com/myacc/teststuff.git

[image]

Any ideas what might be wrong? :/

Comment: Are you certain that the credentials be correct, assuming this repo not be public?

Comment: 100% sure it's correct. I have copy/pasted the clone url directly from Github to Sourcetree

Comment: But I'm not asking about the URL, I'm asking whether you have configured the permissions properly to make it possible to even clone in the first place.  As you know, not every repo in GitHub can just be cloned by the public.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I misunderstood. Yes permissions should be fine. I can commit/push with Github desktop, but not with Sourcetree.

Answer (score 2):

First, if you are talking about ssh keys, the url to use should be an ssh one:

```
git@github.com:myacc/teststuff.git
```

Second, since I don't see that repo on your account, it could be a private repo.

Make sure yu have enabled Git on SourceTree (I prefer [using the system Git](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/using-embedded-git-or-system-git-in-sourcetree-785323587.html), meaning a Git I have installed myself)